# In BJT CE configuration, is it correct to write Ie = Ic+ Ib? Shouldn't it be Ie= Ic-Icbo + Ib?

Tags: bjt

This is my understanding.. 
The collector current Ic comprises of two components.
1)alpha times the Ie, 
2)the reverse saturation current Icbo.

If this is correct how can Ie = Ic+ Ib be true?
It should be Ie= Ic-Icbo + Ib , right?.

Please let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> "The collector current Ic comprises of two components. 1)alpha times
>   the Ie, 2)the reverse saturation current Icbo...."

$$I_C = \alpha I_E + I_{CBO} \tag{a}$$

Now,
$$I_E = I_C +I_B\tag{b}$$

then,
$$I_E=\alpha I_E + I_{CBO} + I_B\tag{c}$$

I think you used the approximation that \$I_C = \alpha I_E\$ somewhere in your calculation. Remember that \$I_C = \alpha I_E\$ is valid only if \$I_{CBO} = 0\$.

Comment: Is (c) equivalent to \$I_E = I_{C_{majority}} + I_{CBO} + I_B\$ ?

Comment: @philS Yes. It is..

Answer (score 0):

You are just mixing up two different things.

Internal behaviour of a BJT can be seen in different ways, with different models and levels of abstraction, starting out from very physic view with diffusion and drift currents and ending up in one of those "electronics friendly" model like Ebers-Moll I guess you were talking about or some even simpler IC=beta IB "black box"

In turn seen from outside BJT is however a tripole and hence KCL must in any case hold true. So looking into outside terminals it is quite true  that IE=IC+IB

*(by the way you must always specify "where the arrow is pointing to" like in the picture below as another widly used convension is all arrows in and hence IE+IB+IE=0)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f131l7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So recapping from outside IE=IC+IB but each of these currents can be further studied and made got down to their own physical meaning.

Comment: ".... their own physical meaning." That means (with plain words): Ic consists of two currents with different directions (one much larger than the other one).

Comment: So if Ic consists of two currents, one being caused by emitter and one by temperature, when we say  IE=IC+IB, we are not actually considering the part due to temperature right?
And the correct equation would be IE=(IC-tempPart)+IB. Is this correct?

Comment: @ibsenv: No - the equation IE=IC+IB always holds. There are three nodes and three currents and Kirchhof´s current law is always valid. Of course, currents may change their values due to environmental conditions..